# Load multiple KMZ files or geoRSS feeds into Google Maps

Tags: rss, google-maps, geolocation, kml

I have multiple KMZ files/geoRSS feeds I want to use as different layers in Google Maps (Not Earth).

How would I do this?

I know of two ways to use KMZ files with Maps:

1. **My Maps** You can import KMZ files to your heart's content, but the problem with this is that it paginates the results after about 10 items. I want to have both KMZ files displayed, in their entirety, simultaneously. *Consequently, this route does not work.*
2. **Maps search for KMZ file** This groups the entire KMZ file into one layer. Awesome and exactly what I want. However, ***how do I get this to work with multiple KMZ files?***

I can't simply combine the data into one KMZ file because I'm wanting to combine a live geoRSS feed of planning applications with the shape file I link to in point 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this using a KML file which contains Network Links to your KMZ files.

The nice thing about the Network Links is that it doesn't have to be KMZ files it can be a script or feed that outputs a KMZ/KML file.  There is a demo of how to do this [here](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html) under the section **Generating a Random Placemark**

Basically you create a KML file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Network Links full of awesome</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <open>0</open>
    <description>Network link example to show how to overlay several KMZ files on one map</description>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 7</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 7</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag7.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 6</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 6</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag6.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 5</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 5</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 4</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 4</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag4.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 3</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 3</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag3.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 2</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 2</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag2.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
      <name>Earthquakes Mag 1</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Earthquakes Mag 1</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/epic/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag1.kmz</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

Then in Google Maps, search using the full URL pointing to your KML file and you get something like this:

[image: Google Maps Multiple Overlays]

This displays 7 different KMZ files on the same map but using only one URL - the KML file with all the links in.

Comment: That's brilliant, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Fantastic answer, totally worked. Thank you very much! Just one question -- it seems KML doesn't validate if the network link has characters such as ? or & in it, which is problematic for me, given my feed uses GET request arguments (I.e., site.com/feed/?type=stuff&strict=true). Know any way around that? I can't use mod_rewrite, because I'm using ScraperWiki.

Comment: @aendrew Hmm, can't you off load the processing of the feed to a script file and then link the script file in your `<networkLink>` element. That way you just point to a script and the script calls the actual URL with the query string parameters.

Comment: Correction, it's just the `&` character that muddles up Google Maps. I can pass it a feed with only one argument and it's fine. It stops validating when I add an ampersand. Replacing it with %26 doesn't seem to work; ScraperWiki interprets that as a literal and sees my query string as `?feed=appeals&true` instead of `?feed=appeals&strict=true` (also truncating my second variable in the process). Any thoughts?

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm asking the ScraperWiki folks if they have a way of turning mod_rewrite on; if not, I'll use what you suggest.

Comment: Note for anyone coming across this from Google -- if your URL has ampersands in it (I.e., GET arguments), put the URL in <![CDATA[..]]> tags. So, that would look like: `<Link><href><![CDATA[http://views.scraperwiki.com/run/hackney_council_planning_and_appeals_rss_output/?feed=appeals&strict=true]]></href></Link>` Everything parses fine!